# Error in Async related with doInBackground when trying to use HTTPPOST

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

I'm new to android development and I was trying to receive an xml file from the server after sending a request.

So I'm trying to connect to a server and send an xml string with httppost but for some reason I'm getting an error on my asyncTask. I tried doing it without the async task but new android devices raise an exception...

```
private class Connection extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

                    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
                        connect();
                        return null;
                    }

                }
    private void connect() {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://dev.engineersnetwork.net/enetdevservices/");

        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><soap12:Body><LineTest xmlns=\"http://www.engineersnetwork.net/enetdevservices/\"></LineTest></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>", HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httppost.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            TextView tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData);
            tvData.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here's the log:

```
    05-16 15:42:32.220: D/libEGL(8865): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-16 15:42:32.230: D/libEGL(8865): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-16 15:42:32.230: D/libEGL(8865): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-16 15:42:32.260: D/OpenGLRenderer(8865): Enabling debug mode 0
05-16 15:42:32.310: W/dalvikvm(8865): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412d62a0)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4876)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:948)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15245)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15245)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15245)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15245)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15245)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6623)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3727)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3585)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3560)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at vancert.test2.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:52)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at vancert.test2.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:39)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at vancert.test2.MainActivity$Connection.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:34)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-16 15:42:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(8865):     ... 5 more
05-16 15:42:42.260: I/Process(8865): Sending signal. PID: 8865 SIG: 9
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

```
 TextView tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData);
 tvData.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
```

this code can not run inside `doInBackground`. It has to be executed by the `UI Thread` .

Use an `Handler` or `runOnUiThread` to post a runnable to the `UI Thread` message queue

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these error because your asynctask is running in background thread and you          are setting value of textview which is on main ui thread.You cant use main ui thread views from background thread.
    Put these code inside your on postexecute() of asynctask.

```
TextView tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData);
 tvData.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
```